# how to publish Angular Universal to azure website?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, publish

Please someone correct me if this is wrong.

1. create backend, dotnet core api
2. create angular universal enabled site using backend api
3. publish #1 as separate instance (**dotnet core** app service)
4. publish #2 as another separate instance. (**node.js** app service)

I am trying to get the site to be SEO friendly.  Or maybe even just plain dot net core mvc project with Razor pages.

Comment: Is your question about what technology stack you should use? There is so many options and almost all of them you can host in Azure. My preference is having front and backend in one Azure App Service using Node and Express as API backend and VueJs or Angular as frontend. But it really depends on your use case

Comment: are you saying you can host a project with dotnet backend and angular front end on Node.js app service instance?  I didn't know Node.js instance can run dot net framework/core

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you described would work and since you are charged by the app service *plan* and not the app service you can host both apps in the same plan and not incur extra charges. However you can also add Angular to the front end of a .NET core application and deploy to a single app in Azure as well. Please see [this](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) article for reference

Comment: My main thing is to get Angular Universal to work and it says it will only work with Node.js and express environment.  So my question is can I combine dotnet core & angular app, as you mentioned, run on node.js app service instance?  thanks

Comment: If you are set on Angular Universal then, yes, you should proceed with two apps. One with each run time.

Comment: I am not set on Angular, I am trying to find a best solution.  Do you recommend another solution?   Is React better?  or should I just use core+mvc or core+razor page

Comment: The debate of Angular vs React is endless. But the solution you described is fine.